# Create Tkinter buttons in a loop that reference each other

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a series of tkinter buttons with a loop that are .grid'd to their own respective frames. I want every button to have a function that .tkraises the next frame in the list of frames that I create. Any idea how? Here's what I've got. The buttons/ frames are created I think but the .tkraise function doesn't work. Thanks

```py
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

## Define root and geometry
root = Tk()
root.geometry('200x200')

# Define Frames
winlist = list()
winlist = Frame(root, bg='red'), Frame(root, bg='green'), Frame(root, bg='blue')

# Configure Rows
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

# Place Frames
for window in winlist:
    window.grid(row=0, column = 0, sticky = 'news')

# Raises first window 'To the top'
winlist[0].tkraise()

# Function to raise 'window' to the top
def raise_frame(window):
    window.tkraise()

d = {}
count = 0
for x in range(0, 3):
    d["label{0}".format(x)] = Label(winlist[x], text = "label{0}".format(x))
    if count <=1:
        try:
            d["button{0}".format(x)] = Button(winlist[x], text = "button{0}".format(x), command = raise_frame(winlist[x+1]))
            d["button{0}".format(x)].pack(side=TOP)
        except:
            pass
    else:
        d["label{0}".format(x)].pack(side=TOP)
    count += 1

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: btw, to mention, `winlist` is NOT a list, it is a tuple

Answer (score 1):

The issue is on the `command` option of the line:

```py
d["button{0}".format(x)] = Button(winlist[x], text = "button{0}".format(x), command = raise_frame(winlist[x+1]))
```

It will execute `raise_frame(winlist[x+1])` immediately and then assign the result (which is `None`) to `command` option.  Therefore, clicking the button later does nothing.

You need to use `lambda` instead:

```py
d["button{0}".format(x)] = Button(winlist[x], text="button{0}".format(x),
                                  command=lambda x=x: raise_frame(winlist[x+1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question. instead of using frames I went back to creating Tk() objects. I made a loop that runs a function that creates Tk() objects and passed in a variable that carried the count of my loop. I used that count to change information on each Tk() object and instead made the 'command =' of each button include a Tk().destroy function. This creates all the windows I wanted all at once and I can perform an action and exit the window. It's progress. Thanks,

Tim,

Comment: ok, this sound like a horrible idea, first of there should be only one `Tk` instance, for more windows You should then use `Toplevel`... tho I will try to provide the answer with frames